# % of total bar chart in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to display the % of grand total rather than a sum in power bi. I feel like in the old power bi I was able to select a bar chart that was % of total but in the new one I am unable to do this.

I have tried creating a measure:

Labor Hours % =
DIVIDE(SUM('TABLE'[Hours]), [Total Hours])

but this is not working either.

Comment: Update your question with more details. "not working" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 100% stacked bar chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Labor Hours % = DIVIDE(SUM('TABLE'[Hours]), [Total Hours])

How about
DIVIDE ( SUM('table'[Hours]), CALCULATE(SUM('table'[Hours]),REMOVEFILTERS('table'))
)?